# How does one create custom output stream for subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, subprocess

I am trying to get realtime output of a subprocess.call by defining my own output stream but it doesn't seem to work.

Reason: I want to run a subprocess and get output of that call to both stdout(in realtime so i can look at the script and see current progress) as well as logging it to a file

subprocess.py:

```
import time

while True:
    print("Things")
    time.sleep(1)
```

mainprocess.py

```
import subprocess
import io

class CustomIO(io.IOBase):
    def write(self, str):
        print("CustomIO: %s"%str)
        # logging to be implemented here

customio = CustomIO()
subprocess.call(["python3", "print_process.py"], stdout=customio)
```

But when i run this code i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                   
    File "call_test.py", line 9, in <module>                           
        subprocess.call(["python3", "print_process.py"], stdout=customio)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call         
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:                           
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 823, in __init__     
        errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)    
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1302, in _get_handles
        c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()                                       
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

So, anyone have any clue if this is possible?

Am i inheriting the wrong baseclass?

Am i not overloading the proper methods?

Or am i completely off the rails and should be going about this in a completely different way?

Comment: subprocess expect a real file object with real os file      descriptor, try PIPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to process the output of a subprocess, you need to pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. However, `call()` and `run()` will both wait until the process is finished before making it available, so you cannot handle it in real time using these functions.

You need to use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess as sp

def handle_output(output_line):
    ...

my_process = sp.Popen(["python3", "print_process.py"],
                      stdout=sp.PIPE,
                      universal_newlines=True) # changes stdout from bytes to text

for line in my_process.stdout:
    handle_output(line)

my_process.wait()
```

**Update:** Make sure to flush the output buffer in your child process:

```
while True:
    print("Things", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This does not seem to handle output in realtime either? when i run this it waits for subprocess to be completed before printing anything

Comment: my apologies - for some reason it worked when I tested with `["yes"]`. See update.

Comment: Nice, is there any way to do this without adding a flush in the child process. In my real case it's not a python script but instead a program of which i have no controll over.

Comment: I think there are a couple of ways to approach this, and it's probably worth its own question.

Comment: ok, thank you. will accept this answer then since it solved the provided problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify and open stream with a file descriptor. `fileno` isn't implemented for `io.IOBase` because this is just an in-memory stream:

> [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)
>
> `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` specify the executed program’s standard
>   input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.
>   Valid values are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a
>   positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`. `PIPE` indicates
>   that a new pipe to the child should be created. `DEVNULL` indicates that
>   the special file `os.devnull` will be used. With the default settings of
>   `None`, no redirection will occur;

So you might use sockets, pipes, and open files as `stdout`, the file descriptor is passed to the child process as it's stdout. I didn't use sockets with `subprocess.Popen` though, but I expect them to work, I believe what matters here is the file descriptor to the child, not what type of object the file descriptor points to.